# Magento 2 JS issue

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.2.6

on my Magento 2 I use Porto latest theme version. Sometimes language and currency drops dont work. I must always restart page to fix.
I got following JS error

```
    Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
(index):640 Uncaught ReferenceError: mageplazaSearchProducts is not defined
    at (index):640
    at Object.execCb (b29f13fc0670ca942204bec99d0282e1.js:1650)
    at Module.check (b29f13fc0670ca942204bec99d0282e1.js:866)
    at Module.<anonymous> (b29f13fc0670ca942204bec99d0282e1.js:1113)
    at b29f13fc0670ca942204bec99d0282e1.js:132
    at b29f13fc0670ca942204bec99d0282e1.js:1156
    at each (b29f13fc0670ca942204bec99d0282e1.js:57)
    at Module.emit (b29f13fc0670ca942204bec99d0282e1.js:1155)
    at Module.check (b29f13fc0670ca942204bec99d0282e1.js:917)
    at Module.<anonymous> (b29f13fc0670ca942204bec99d0282e1.js:1113)
```

Comment: The Issues is from the third party extension : mageplazaSearchProducts
    Try to disable this and then check.

Comment: Thanks its work